# regex to detect strings which involves only (at least one) letter and special character

Tags: python, regex

What might be a good regex to detect strings which involves only (at least one) letter and special character? I checked this, [How to check if a string contains only [numbers OR special characters] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438570/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers-or-special-characters-in-python), but it didn't help.

I want to detect strings which involves only (at least one) letter and special character in python.

Comment: Did you try any regex? Also include few valid and invalid examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
if re.search('\w+[!@#$%*()]+', string) or re.search('[!@#$%*()]+\w+', string):
    do_something()
```